# Proving that the given function is not piecewise continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = x\,\text{sgn}\left({\sin(\frac{1}{x})}\right)$where sgn is the signum function..
For $x\neq0$ and $f(0) = 0$ , how to prove that the given function is not piecewise continuous on $[-1,1]$.
Kindly help !

Comment: Do you have a definition of "piecewise continuous" to work from?

Comment: Yes , i have , If a function f is piecewise continuous on [a,b] , then f is uniformly continuous on finite number of sub-intervals of [a,b] @HenningMakholm